# How to secure online videos in an education portal?

Tags: security, video-streaming

I am working on an online video training website and I want to secure my videos so that no one can download the videos. Can any one help me how can I restrict video download or how can I make them more difficult to download? Should I convert them into flash files?

Comment: There's no way to fully restrict video download, because you still need people to be able to view it. It would be like asking, how do I show a webpage to my users, but don't allow them to download the source?

Comment: People will have to download your videos in order to view them, whatever format you use. If you don't want them downloaded don't put them on the Web.

Comment: @DaveChen Mike What if I make them flash? Will it provide security?

Comment: It would be better to ask how to make it more difficult to download the videos.  As the two commenters above said you cannot prevent a determined person from copying the videos.

Comment: @DaveChen Then how can I make them more difficult to download?

Comment: @MikeW Then how can I make them more difficult to download?

Comment: To make it more difficult to download, I would start with using Flash.  Big downside is that iOS devices don't support it, so that may be a dealbreaker.  @DaveChen 's suggestions below look good too.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the file download by using hotlink protection restricting the direct requests to file.
And data stored for buffering is completely differnt.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: It is an option provided by Hosting Service, if you just place a video player and provide it with a link then anyone with the link can access the file and download it. Let's say you have an image hello.jpg located in home directory of your website, if any one tries to access that file using url http://domain/hello.jpg their access is denied to open image. This is done by blocking extension .jpg similarly block video extention to prevent access to it. Contact your hosting provider on details how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can make it more difficult for users to download videos from your site.

1. Create protected links to video assets

   This means keeping your videos off the document root. You'll want your server to create a one click link that will output the video. This will stop people from going to the asset link directly and attempting to download via the browser (A browser extension can still rip the video with ease).
2. Use RTMP or segmented video streaming

   The video will be in served in chunks, which makes it difficult to download it all together (Of course, there's specialized software that will do this in a cinch though).
3. Enforce rate limits on speed and simultaneous downloads

   This means putting download speed caps, and making it take longer to download the video. This won't effect normal viewing because a normal user will sit there and time will pass for the video to buffer slowly. However, for a user attempting to download the entire video, it'll take much longer. As for limits of simultaneous downloads, this simply means from an IP, there are a maximum number of downloads allotted. So a certain user can't watch 5 videos at the same time (This wouldn't work in a school setting though, because everyone has the same IP on school computers).
4. Notify users that these videos are copyright, and republishing them is against policy

   Students, for the most part are downloading these videos to watch later and/or to share with other students. Adding this really just tries to deter people who decide to re-upload these videos -- which is what you don't want.